# executeQueryAsync callback function execute occasionally

Tags: sharepoint

I have to create publishing page with custom layout using JSOM and the code is working fine. But in my executeQueryAsync success callback, i am trying to get id of the item created. So, sometimes i get the alert with id and sometimes page refreshes without executing success callback. can someone guide me?

```
        wikiPage.set_item("Title",pageName1)
        wikiPage.update();
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 camlQuery.set_viewXml(
                  "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query>" +
                  "<Where>" +
                     "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + pageName + "</Value></Eq>" +
                  "</Where>" +
                  "</Query></View>");
 collListItem = wikiPages.getItems(camlQuery);
 ctx.load(collListItem);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {    
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    alert(oListItem.get_id());} 
}),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the page when you updating instead of querying again.

Demo:

```
wikiPage.update();
            ctx.load(wikiPage);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    debugger;
                    alert(wikiPage.get_item("ID"));
                },
                error);
```